# Validation Rule for Account to request fields not to be blank to change Stage isnt working

Tags: validation-rule, account, isblank

This is my Validation Rule I do not understand where is the issue
If you are no admin, and CEO hasnt approoved it you shouldnt be able to change Account Stage without filling out infor for company name, address, shareholder and exec, where is the error?

```
AND(
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",

CEO_Approved__c = FALSE,

ISBLANK(Company_Lng_Name__c),
ISBLANK(Shareholder__c),
ISBLANK(Executive__c),
ISBLANK(BillingAddress),

ISPICKVAL(Type,"Partner"),

OR(
ISPICKVAL( Partner_Stage__c ,"P4"),
ISPICKVAL(Partner_Stage__c ,"P5"),
ISPICKVAL(Partner_Stage__c ,"P6"),
ISPICKVAL(Partner_Stage__c ,"P7 "))
```

Comment: On first glance I think your missing a bracket that closes your AND statement, try changing `ISPICKVAL(Partner_Stage__c ,"P7 ")` to `ISPICKVAL(Partner_Stage__c ,"P7"))`

Comment: @developer__c that was my mistake, when copying the formula, but it still doesn't work, a user could change to stage 4 with Shareholder and Executive fields blank, I dont understand where is the error still..

Answer (score 0):

If all 4 fields need to be filled in, then you need an OR() for that field grouping.  If any field is left blank, the formula evaluates to TRUE and the validation rule fires:

```
OR(
    ISBLANK(Company_Lng_Name__c),
    ISBLANK(Shareholder__c),
    ISBLANK(Executive__c),
    ISBLANK(BillingAddress)
),
```